# Doesn't it necessary to write verification code for in-app-billing?

Tags: in-app-billing

I am writing code for in-app-billing for my app.
I saw sample code here https://medium.com/@patpatchpatrick/adding-the-google-play-billing-library-to-your-application-fbeb9ec03151
There is no code for purchase verification. 
I mean it does not use BASE_64_ENCODED_PUBLIC_KEY at all.
But TrivialDrive_v2 has code for purchase verification in verifyValidSignature method.
My question is that "Is verification required or just recommendation?"